# How to find SQLITE database version in pycharm db extension

Tags: sqlite, pycharm

[image]

I'm working in windows  and I'm using pycharm to code in and manage my sqqlite db. How to I check the sqllite version. I tried the standard terminal command as in the screen shot, but it does not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tried it on Windows but on Linux you can import the sqlite3 on the python console of PyCharm and then enter

```
sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

to get the version of SQLite library. I do not see the reason for not being the same on Windows as well.

To add on that you can do the same through the terminal by calling the Python IDLE Shell by typing `python` and then:

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
```